# Why do pseudo forces act in direction opposite to that of acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I didnt know what to write in the body but a simple answer would help a lot, thanks.

Comment: If you write $\sum{forces}=ma$, then in the frame of reference of an observer moving with acceleration a, you appear to have equilibrium with $$\sum{(forces-ma)}=0$$So it is as if you have an additional force of -ma.

Answer (score 2):

Because according to you, you are not accelerating.

Let's imagine you're in a car that is accelerating according to an outside observer.  Your seat will push you forward and make you accelerate with the car.  But according to you, it "feels like" you are being pushed into the seat.  There's no physical force causing this, it's just a pseudo force as a result of being in an accelerating frame, and selfishly claiming that you are not moving in your own frame of reference (therefore real acceleration must be cancelled by a pseudo acceleration).

Another example is spinning on a merry-go-round.  Suppose the children's playground toy is spinning and you're on it.  Because you're doing circular motion you are accelerating inwards.  But according to you, you are not doing circular motion -- in fact you are not moving.  But there is a force pulling you towards the centre (e.g. you're holding onto the bars).  If you're not accelerating in your point of view, there must be another "pseudo force" (the centrifugal force) acting opposite to the real force causing the circular acceleration.  Another way of thinking about this is at any instant on the merry-go-round, your body wants to go in a tangent to the circle, but it can't because you're holding on to the centre.

Both examples above show pseudo forces acting opposite to the acceleration as you've said, but not all pseudo forces do this.  The Coriolis force is another pseudo force experienced by rotating bodies, and this always acts in a direction perpendicular to your velocity (not necessarily the acceleration).